# How to delete a row if it has a -1 in a certain column in R data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
SNP     CLST    A1      A2      FRQ     IMP     POS     CHR     BVAL
rs4030303       French  G       A       1       1       72434   1       994
rs1933024       French  G       A       1       1       -1      -1      -1
rs6594028       French  A       G       0       1       554461  1       988
rs10458597      French  C       T       1       1       554484  1       988
rs9701055       French  T       C       0       1       555296  1       988
rs9699599       French  A       G       1       1       558185  1       988
```

If there is a -1 in the BVAL column, I would like to delete the row. How is that possible?

My desired output is:

```
SNP     CLST    A1      A2      FRQ     IMP     POS     CHR     BVAL
rs4030303       French  G       A       1       1       72434   1       994
rs6594028       French  A       G       0       1       554461  1       988
rs10458597      French  C       T       1       1       554484  1       988
rs9701055       French  T       C       0       1       555296  1       988
rs9699599       French  A       G       1       1       558185  1       988
```

Comment: `dat = dat[dat$BVAL != -1, ]`

Comment: See [here](http://statmethods.net/management/subset.html) for some more info on subsetting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different options, the base R solution is (assuming your dataframe is called `dat`):

```
dat = dat[dat$BVAL != -1, ]
```

, redefining `dat` as all the rows of `dat` where the column BVAL does not have the value of -1.